# Integrating own log-in mechanism with Xbox Live

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, xbox-one, xbox-live

We are porting our Unity3D game to Xbox One Creators program and we think about how we should integrate our own log-in system with Xbox Live.

We are currently (in standalone PC version) using our own written log-in mechanism and account management system backed by the proprietary server application. Registration is mandatory because this is a multiplayer game. In the registration, step user is needed to fill-in registration form with a chosen nickname, mail address, and password.
On Xbox One, of course, we want to avoid this step and leverage existing user's Xbox Live account.

In Xbox Live SDK there is *XboxLiveUser* object which we get after user logs-in and we will use *XboxUserId* property as a way to uniquely identify the user in our system. But how can we authorize him? We understand that *XboxUserId* is easily available for all other games and even other users and we need some secret passphrase which we will use to authenticate against.
Is there any way to get unique hash per application per Xbox live user?

We see that *XboxLiveUser* has method *GetTokenAndSignatureAsync* which returns *GetTokenAndSignatureResult* object which contains *XboxUserHash* property. Is this safe to use this string as passphrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XboxUserHash` property that is returned by the `GetToken*` methods cannot be used as a user identifier.  It is likely to change each time a user authenticates with Xbox Live.

As of November 2017, there is no way for an Xbox Creators Program game to authenticate an Xbox Live user on a non-XboxLive service.  The best you would be able to do would be to have your game client verify that the user can authenticate with Xbox Live and get the same XboxUserId as the one they are using to authenticate with your service.

Comment: We eneded up generating random token and storing it in _Xbox Live Title Storage_. We then use _XboxUserId_ and this token to log-in into our services automatically on any device where user is signed in Xbox Live service. Do you think it's correct approach?

Comment: That seems like a reasonable solution to me!